# Spring boot plus okta saml2 integration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, saml-2.0, okta

I am trying to integrate an Spring boot application with okta saml2.0
I am trying to intergrate my application with okta sso saml2.

Okta saml2.0 is configured with https for SSO as well as metadata url

Spring boot version : 2.7.12

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-saml2-service-provider</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
        <artifactId>opensaml-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
        <artifactId>opensaml-saml-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
        <artifactId>opensaml-saml-impl</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Getting an error "Invalid Destination"

On checking the log i find the below

**Destination** - **https**://xxxxxxxxxx.stage.xxxxx.xx/login/saml2/sso/okta

**assertionConsumerServiceLocation** - **http**://xxxxxxxxxx.stage.xxxxx.xx/login/saml2/sso/okta

issue is due to the mismatch between http and https.
Fails in below code
Open saml4 authentication provider

if (StringUtils.hasText(destination) && !destination.equals(location)) {

String message = "Invalid destination [" + destination + "] for SAML response [" + response.getID()+ "]";

To fix above issue, i updated property file with :

*spring.security.saml2.relyingparty.registration.okta.acs.location=https://settlement.stage-v2.xxxxxx.xxx/login/saml2/sso/{registrationId}
spring.security.saml2.relyingparty.registration.okta.entityId=https://settlement.stage-v2.xxxxxxx.xxx/saml2/service-provider-metadata/{registrationId}*

Now i am getting an error :

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://settlement.stage-v2.xxxxxx.xxx/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure manifest '**http**://settlement.stage-v2.xxxxxx.xxx/saml2/authenticate/okta'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Please let me know how should the fix the issue in a proper way .